# IllegalArgumentException on MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get few frames from a video file. And getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` in the `setDataSource` line below.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
String path=root + "master" + File.separator +"master.mp4";

Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(path);
File myFile = new File(path);



MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(myFile.getAbsolutePath()); //getting error here
ArrayList<Bitmap> rev=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

//Create a new Media Player
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);

int millis = mp.getDuration();
for(int i=0;i<millis;i+=100){
    Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    rev.add(bitmap);}
```

> Error Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.mm.video, PID: 11576
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.mm.video/in.mm.video.RecognizeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:71)
at in.mm.video.RecognizeActivity.onCreate(RecognizeActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: use getCanonicalPath or simple getPath insted of myFile.getAbsolutePath() let me Know if its work

Comment: tried both . same error

Comment: @KudukkuK always try to add the error log which is responsible for the crash. Sometimes provides more information as to the reason for the error other than the exception.

Comment: try this setDataSource(path,new HashMap<String, String>()) before giving path please check path vie log and see what u gets in path

Comment: Why don't you use File.separator instead of "/"?

Comment: @Ashvin solanki setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA path is /storage/emulated/0/master/master.mp4 and i have a file there

Comment: @forpas both r same

Comment: are u sure master.mp4 file presented in folder /storage/emulated/0/master ? please check the file details and see the file

Comment: @xar-e-ahmer,  can u check this?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki the file is there.

Comment: @xareahmer, can you check this?

Comment: @KudukkuK check `if(myFile.exist()){//....code}`

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki, file is there in the path. I have verified with file.exists and physically !.